# Jquery week calendar not working in ie

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

When loading jquery week calender it is not getting loaded in ie only header is getting loaded
but when I am pressing F12 to see console of ie n refresh page calendar get loaded.
It is working good on other browsers.

Comment: My assumption this is in IE8 and below? Perhaps you should show some code.

Comment: It is impossible to help you with the information you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue....guess ie has a problem with console.log
as i had removed those it  started working,. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you have a trailing comma in your parameter list. IE will choke on trailing commas all the time in js.

Comment: Checking for that but not finding any :(

Comment: in which ie version you have tested?

Comment: jQuery Advice For Dealing With Stupid Internet Explorer http://www.ventanazul.com/webzine/articles/stupid-internet-explorer have a look at this URL